# Ignore np.where after first match for Pandas time series data

Tags: python, pandas

As per the following example I need to make my code ignore the np.where after first match for time series data.

So on the `2014-03-04 14:00:00` row the np.where gives a 1.0 on the test_output column and, as would be expected, also on the next row.  I only want this to trigger once ever.  I will show desired output at the end of the question.

Thanks for looking at the question.

Data frame generated for test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2014-03-04 09:00:00', end='2014-03-04 16:15:00', freq='1h') + pd.date_range(start='2014-03-05 09:00:00', end='2014-03-05 16:15:00', freq='1h'), data={'test_1': np.nan})

df['test_1'][5:16]=1.0

df['test_output'] = np.where(df['test_1'] == 1.0,1.0,np.nan);
df

test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 10:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 11:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 12:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 13:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 14:00:00 1.0 1.0
2014-03-04 15:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 16:00:00 1.0 1.0
2014-03-05 09:00:00 1.0 1.0
```

This is the desired output:

```
test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 10:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 11:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 12:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 13:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 14:00:00 1.0 1.0
2014-03-04 15:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 16:00:00 1.0 NaN
2014-03-05 09:00:00 1.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) on the mask to set the first row:

```
In [30]:
df.loc[df[df['test_1'] == 1.0].first_valid_index(),'test_output'] = 1.0
df

Out[30]:
                     test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 10:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 11:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 12:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 13:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 14:00:00     1.0          1.0
2014-03-04 15:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-04 16:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 09:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 10:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 11:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 12:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 13:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 14:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 15:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 16:00:00     1.0          NaN
```

breaking the above down:

```
In [32]:
df['test_1'] == 1.0

Out[32]:
2014-03-04 09:00:00    False
2014-03-04 10:00:00    False
2014-03-04 11:00:00    False
2014-03-04 12:00:00    False
2014-03-04 13:00:00    False
2014-03-04 14:00:00     True
2014-03-04 15:00:00     True
2014-03-04 16:00:00     True
2014-03-05 09:00:00     True
2014-03-05 10:00:00     True
2014-03-05 11:00:00     True
2014-03-05 12:00:00     True
2014-03-05 13:00:00     True
2014-03-05 14:00:00     True
2014-03-05 15:00:00     True
2014-03-05 16:00:00     True
Freq: BH, Name: test_1, dtype: bool

In [33]:
df[df['test_1'] == 1.0].first_valid_index()

Out[33]:
Timestamp('2014-03-04 14:00:00', offset='BH')
```

You can do it using `np.where` by again masking against the df so it produces `NaN` where the condition is false by comparing the np array against 1.0:

```
In [41]:
df.loc[df[np.where(df['test_1'] == 1.0, 1.0, 0) == 1].first_valid_index(), 'test_output'] = 1.0

df
Out[41]:
                     test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 10:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 11:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 12:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 13:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-04 14:00:00     1.0          1.0
2014-03-04 15:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-04 16:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 09:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 10:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 11:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 12:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 13:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 14:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 15:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-03-05 16:00:00     1.0          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first index and then change the value

```
index = np.where(df['test_1'] == 1.0)[0][0]
df.iloc[index]['test_output'] = df.iloc[index]['test_1'] or # =1
```