# Using groupby ("1d") and first_valid_index together

Tags: python, pandas

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183182/ignore-np-where-after-first-match-for-pandas-time-series-data/38183664#38183664) post shows how to use `first_valid_index` to find the first occurrence of a value in a dataframe column.  How do I use first_valid_index along with a daily groupby in order to find first occurrence each day for the same example dataframe as shown in the linked post?

This is the groupby code I need to use:

```
grouper = pd.TimeGrouper("1d")
```

Edit:

When I use the `lambda` and `apply` approach it gives correct output.  I am unable to send this output to a new column `['test_output']` though as it just shows NaT:

```
df['test_output'] = df.groupby(grouper)['test_1'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())

df
Out[9]:
test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00 NaN NaT
2014-03-04 10:00:00 NaN NaT
2014-03-04 11:00:00 NaN NaT
2014-03-04 12:00:00 NaN NaT
2014-03-04 13:00:00 NaN NaT
2014-03-04 14:00:00 1.0 NaT
2014-03-04 15:00:00 1.0 NaT
2014-03-04 16:00:00 1.0 NaT
2014-03-05 09:00:00 1.0 NaT
```

Comment: with `groupby` you can just do `df.groupby(grouper).first()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) on your `groupby` object:

```
In [95]:
df.groupby(grouper).first()

Out[95]:
            test_1
2014-03-04     1.0
2014-03-05     1.0
```

should work, the above was generated using the same data as your linked question

**EDIT**

I think the above is actually correct as it's different from calling `head(1)` for instance:

```
In [3]:
df.groupby(grouper).head(1)

Out[3]:
                     test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-03-05 09:00:00       1            1
```

but you can also call `first_valid_index` using a `lambda` with `apply`:

```
In [6]:
df.groupby(grouper)['test_1'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())

Out[6]:
2014-03-04   2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-05   2014-03-05 09:00:00
Name: test_1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**EDIT**

To add this back as a column is a bit tricky, this is because you're trying to match the orig index against the new daily grouped `groupby` object so it won't align which is why you `NaT`. What you can do is call `to_series` on the index, the reason we want this is so we can call `map`, and access just the `date` attribute. `map` will perform a lookup so it will match on the date on the `groupby` result and return the first valid date as desired:

```
In [136]:
df['first'] = df.index.to_series().dt.date.map(df.groupby(grouper)['test_1'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index()))
df

Out[136]:
                     test_1  test_output               first
2014-03-04 09:00:00     NaN          NaN 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 10:00:00     NaN          NaN 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 11:00:00     NaN          NaN 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 12:00:00     NaN          NaN 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 13:00:00     NaN          NaN 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 14:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 15:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-04 16:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-04 14:00:00
2014-03-05 09:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 10:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 11:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 12:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 13:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 14:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 15:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
2014-03-05 16:00:00     1.0          1.0 2014-03-05 09:00:00
```

Comment: thanks again.  The issue here is my understanding of groupby and it may not be the correct approach for my task.  I am looking to return the first time of the day this 1.0 happens as per my previous post but the groupby is just giving me the day and not the time of day.

Comment: Thanks EdChum.  This is getting close with the Lambda apply approach as this returns the required output.  Unfortunately I can't send this data to another column 'test_output' as it just shows NaT values when I use: `df['test_output'] = df.groupby(grouper)['test_1'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())`

Comment: Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Can you edit your question with raw data and updated code to show how you get this error plus what your desired output is as this was never mentioned in your original post

Comment: Hi Ed the data is from the linked post that you helped with previously and I marked as answered.  I can copy and paste here if that help though.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation EdChum