# Pandas: Find first occurrence - on daily basis in a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm struggling with this so any input appreciated.  I want to iterate over the values in a dataframe column and return the first instance when a value is seen every day.  Groupby looked to be a good option for this but when using  `df.groupby(grouper).first()` with `grouper` set at daily the following output is seen.

```
In [95]:
df.groupby(grouper).first()

Out[95]:
            test_1
2014-03-04     1.0
2014-03-05     1.0
```

This is only giving the day the value was seen in test _1 and not reseting the first() on a daily basis which is what I need (see desired output below).

I want to preserve the time this value was seen in the following format:

This is the input dataframe:

```
                  test_1
2014-03-04 09:00:00 NaN
2014-03-04 10:00:00 NaN
2014-03-04 11:00:00 NaN
2014-03-04 12:00:00 NaN
2014-03-04 13:00:00 NaN
2014-03-04 14:00:00 1.0
2014-03-04 15:00:00 NaN
2014-03-04 16:00:00 1.0
2014-03-05 09:00:00 1.0
```

This is the desired output:

```
                 test_1  test_output
2014-03-04 09:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 10:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 11:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 12:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 13:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 14:00:00 1.0 1.0
2014-03-04 15:00:00 NaN NaN
2014-03-04 16:00:00 1.0 NaN
2014-03-05 09:00:00 1.0 NaN
```

I just want to mark the time when an event first occurs in a new column named test_output.

Admins.  Please note this question is different from the other marked as a duplicate as this requires a rolling one day first occurrence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore np.where after first match for Pandas time series data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183182/ignore-np-where-after-first-match-for-pandas-time-series-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using this data:

```
rng = pd.DataFrame( {'test_1': [None, None,None, None, 1,1, 1 , None, None, None,1 , None, None, None,]},  index = pd.date_range('4/2/2014', periods=14, freq='BH'))
rng

                    test_1
2014-04-02 09:00:00     NaN
2014-04-02 10:00:00     NaN
2014-04-02 11:00:00     NaN
2014-04-02 12:00:00     NaN
2014-04-02 13:00:00     1.0
2014-04-02 14:00:00     1.0
2014-04-02 15:00:00     1.0
2014-04-02 16:00:00     NaN
2014-04-03 09:00:00     NaN
2014-04-03 10:00:00     NaN
2014-04-03 11:00:00     1.0
2014-04-03 12:00:00     NaN
2014-04-03 13:00:00     NaN
2014-04-03 14:00:00     NaN
```

The output is this:

```
rng['test_output'] = rng['test_1'].loc[rng.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D'))['test_1'].idxmin()]

                    test_1  test_output
2014-04-02 09:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-02 10:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-02 11:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-02 12:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-02 13:00:00     1.0          1.0
2014-04-02 14:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-04-02 15:00:00     1.0          NaN
2014-04-02 16:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-03 09:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-03 10:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-03 11:00:00     1.0          1.0
2014-04-03 12:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-03 13:00:00     NaN          NaN
2014-04-03 14:00:00     NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Merlin appreciate the help.  I tried your rng DF and it does work with the test data you generated.  Unfortunately when I try this with my dataframe i get an error: I used `data['test_output'] = data['Gap Higher Closed'].loc[data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D'))['Gap Higher Closed'].idxmin()]`

this is the error https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32282382/error.txt

Comment: This is the actual dataframe Im trying to use this on.  `data['Gap Higher Closed'].value_counts()
Out[17]:
1.0    1755
Name: Gap Higher Closed, dtype: int64`

Comment: If the code above works. mark it as correct-- you should ask another question using real part of your data..   add your real and real error to a new question-- code above work for the data you provided in your question.